# Did HPL ever draw his creatures, or see drawings in his lifetime?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, cthulhu-mythos, art

H.P. Lovecraft had a pretty vivid imagination, but did he ever draw out or see others drawings of his creatures from his Cthulhu mythos? If so is there some authoritative, or widely accepted set of drawings?

These are some that I found, but I have no idea if these are 'accurate':

[image] [image]

Comment: Beautiful Elder Thing! That is 100% exactly how I always pictured them. (But probably because HPL's description is so accurate...)

Comment: It's nothing how I pictured them when I meat At the Mountains of Madness, whilst detailed I felt the description lacked any substance linking the part of the description into a whole.

Comment: mhm, you are right. Now that you say it, I remember how I read it and that it took me quite a while to picture the Elder Things. I was stuck at that description and it was difficult to put everything together, but after reading it several times I ended up with an image in my mind that looked just like the picture.

Comment: Keep in mind that HPL suffered from horrific nightmares that were said to inspire his cosmic horrors.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Cthulhu as drawn by H. P. Lovecraft](http://lovecraftzine.com/2012/03/23/cthulhu-drawn-by-h-p-lovecraft-himself/) and [a sculpture based on drawing from Lovecraft.](http://lovecraftzine.com/2012/03/27/cthulhu-sculpture-as-drawn-by-hpl/)  the Elder sign shown below (the "leaf" one, not the "eye" one) was drawn by Lovecraft in a 1930 letter to Clark Ashton Smith.

[image: Cthulhu]

[image: Elder sign]

Comment: Very interesting!!

Answer (score 5):

Here is [a sample](https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/drawings.aspx) of HP Lovecraft's sketches of monsters from (or in preparation for) a number of his works, scans taken from the Brown Digital Repository's Howard P. Lovecraft collection:

| Image | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | "Lovecraft made several pages of notes for [*At the Mountains of Madness*](https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/fiction/mm.aspx), but this illustration of an “Old One” is particularly noteworthy." |
| [image] | "In “[The Call of Cthulhu](https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/fiction/cc.aspx)” (1926), Lovecraft describes a statuette taken from the cultists in the Louisiana swamps. He drew this representation of it for his friend, Robert H. Barlow." |
| [image] | "Although Lovecraft wrote “[Pickman’s Model](https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/fiction/pm.aspx)” in 1926, Lovecraft likely drew this years later for one of his correspondents." |
| [image] | "Lovecraft’s two pages of notes for “[The Shadow out of Time](https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/fiction/sot.aspx)” feature a drawing of a member of the Great Race." |
| [image] | "Contains HPL's illustration for "a tale I am writing". Drawing is of a hoofed monster removing a corpse from a grave". |
| [image] | "Although Lovecraft wrote “[The Colour Out of Space](https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/fiction/cs.aspx)” in 1927, he drew this image of the story’s “blasted heath” in a letter to F. Lee Baldwin eight years later." |

And there is the following, not by Lovecraft himself but included in one of his [letters to Robert Bloch](https://repository.library.brown.edu/studio/item/bdr:425668/):

| Image | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | "With linoleum block illustration of Cthulhu by Robert Barlow." |

Answer (score 4):

Negative information: "Weird Tales" never featured one of his stories on the cover. Positive information: his good friend Clark Ashton Smith was an artist and sculptor who was created Mythosian art: [Shub-Niggurath](http://www.eldritchdark.com/files/galleries/by-cas/shub-niggurath.jpg). Conclusion: CAS was inspired by HPL and vice-versa and that HPL saw some of CAS's works in person at some point.

Comment: The [cover](http://www.philsp.com/data/images/w/weird_tales_192405-06-07.jpg) of the [May-June-July 1924 *Weird Tales*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?62079+c) featured the story ["Imprisoned with the Pharaohs"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41892), ostensibly by [Harry Houdini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Houdini) but actually [ghost-written by Lovecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imprisoned_with_the_Pharaohs), but I guess that doesn't count. Anyway, no alien monsters can be seen on that cover.